# How to make "if(String is found on locally){...}

Tags: android, if-statement, sharedpreferences

I want to make an int statement such that if there is a string saved on the local database, then do whatever. I tried:

```
public class DispatchActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=sharedPref.edit();
        String userIDsaved = sharedPref.getString("user_id", "");
    if(userIDsaved==null){
        Intent startSignUpActivity = new Intent(DispatchActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class);
        DispatchActivity.this.startActivity(startSignUpActivity);
    }
        else{
        Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(DispatchActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        DispatchActivity.this.startActivity(startMainActivity);
    }
...
```

However the app crashes when I do that. This is a dispatch activity, meaning if there is a string found locally, then start the mainactivity. if not,  start the sign up activity. Even If i do have a string saved locally, then it crashes. Please tell me how to do what I mentioned

Crash log:

```
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.alibdeir.signupactivity, PID: 20326
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alibdeir.signupactivity/com.alibdeir.signupactivity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_vpn_key_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020047
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3440)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:88)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:106)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:102)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:88) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:106) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:102) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-11 20:39:40.199 20326-20326/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide the logcat

Comment: It should be, `if("".equals(userIDsaved))` because `sharedPref.getString("user_id", "");` will return empty string default as per second argument. OR use like `String userIDsaved = sharedPref.getString("user_id", null);`

Comment: You have exception in `MainActivity` onCreate() method. Because of  `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: your logcat says - `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_vpn_key_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020047`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.dispatch_activity);
```

I don't see where you are inflating the XML file for MainActivity at all. This should be the second line right after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in your onCreate method.

Also, look in your xml file for MainActivity, specifically where you created your FloatingActionButton. It seems as if you have maybe had a type with this View since it has trouble inflating.

OR

You have no added the correct import into gradle for adding the support library for the FloatingActionButton (v7 design support library)

Make sure this is in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

The problem appears in your MainActivity XML file since the logcat output is telling you that!

Here is how I know what is wrong (from logcat output you linked!)

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Also we have this:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_vpn_key_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020047
```

Which leads me to assume maybe your FloatingActionButton's icon is not found in your drawables/mipmap folder

Comment: Wow. What kind of mistake was that? I accidently put "String userIDsaved = sharedPref.getString("user_id", "");" in MainActivity and I haven't define sharedPreferences. I didn't expect it to be a problem with the MainActivity.Thanks Alot

Comment: No problem. Mark my answer if it helped resolve your issue :)

Comment: by the way Ali, I noticed you are saving user_id in shared preferences and are also using Parse (In your last question). Rather than use shared preferences, take advantage of the Singleton instance of your ParseUser! Do the following: ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); If the 'user' object is null, they are not logged in (Go to signup activity). If the 'user' object ISN'T null, they are logged in (Go to Main Activity)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify default value as `NULL`, since you could save something empty as string either, though crash shouldn't happen. But your could be as this:

```
public class DispatchActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        String userIDsaved = sharedPref.getString("user_id", null);

        if(null == userIDsaved){ //you can also check || userIDsaved.isEmpty()
            startActivity(new Intent(this,SignUpActivity.class));
        } else{
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still crashing when I run it.